# SetState de un Widget desde un hijo (Flutter)

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, programación-móvil

Primero que nada soy nuevo en Flutter. Actualmente tengo varios widgets de tipo StatefulWidget en archivos separados y los junto todos en un padre de tipo también StatefulWidget, Mi objetivo es que al presionar un botón en uno de los hijos de Widget principal poder hacer un setState del Principal. Pues actualmente no tengo ni idea de por donde empezar para resolver este problema, intente usar un Provider para actualizar el estado pero en la animación hace un salto de animación no conveniente. AL que me pueda ayudar muchas gracias.

Comment: Puedes agregar el código de lo que has intentado?

Comment: ¿Estas intentando modificar una variable de tu StatefulWidget principal desde un widget en StatefulWidget?

Comment: te dejo este post que hice hace un tiempo https://medium.com/comunidad-flutter/comunicaci%C3%B3n-entre-widgets-5f61b6c2e56c